# ¿Cómo puedo optimizar la respuesta de un JSON al mostrar en un RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, recyclerview, volley

Estoy creando una pantalla que muestra una lista de datos obtenida desde un JSON en un RecyclerView, pero tengo un problema con la respuesta. El RecyclerView se carga con datos o sin datos dependiendo de la respuesta del JSON.

Si el JSON no ha sido llenado aún envía la lista sin ningún dato. El código que se encarga de traer los datos es el siguiente:

```
 private void jsonObjectRequest() {
        try{
            T_Configuraciones_DBManager t_configuraciones_dbManager = new T_Configuraciones_DBManager(getApplicationContext());
            T_Configuraciones t_configuraciones = t_configuraciones_dbManager.ConsultarConfiguracion(Cons.CONFIGURACION_URL);
            String JSON_URL =  t_configuraciones.getCon_URL() + "/GetReferenciaData";

            final JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, JSON_URL,null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {



                            JSONArray mJsonArray = null;
                            try {
                                mJsonArray = response.getJSONArray("recordset");
                                for(int i=0; i < mJsonArray.length(); i++){
                                    JSONObject mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    GetDataAdapter requisicionData = new GetDataAdapter();
                                    requisicionData.setCodigo(mJsonObject.getString("Nro_Dcto"));
                                    requisicionData.setFecha( mJsonObject.getString("Fecha"));
                                    lstRequisicionData.add(requisicionData);
                                }

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lstRequisicionData.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
            );


            showLoadData(lstRequisicionData);
            //Se envían los datos al adaptador para mostrarlos en el RecyclerView


            queue.add(getRequest);
        }catch (Error e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
```

Aquí se crea la vista del RecyclerView :

```
public void showLoadData(final  List<GetDataAdapter> lstRequisicionData ){
        mAdapter = new DeleteRequisicionData(getApplicationContext(), lstRequisicionData);
    }
```

He tratado de implementar un Timer pero el resultado es el mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero debes entender que lo que estas ejecutando es una operación **asíncrona**.

Cuando ejecutas un método **asíncrono**, desde un método **síncrono**, se ejecutan todas las operaciones del método **síncrono** coordinados en el tiempo (una detras de otra). Pero, que pasa cuando se ejecuta una operación **asíncrona**?, en Java, se ejecutan tareas asíncronas para esperar los resultados de una petición, esto evita bloquear la interfaz del usuario durante la espera de resultados de la petición, por lo que es dependiente de un Callback que te notifica cuando se obtuvo el resultado, en este caso, el método `public void onResponse(JSONObject response)` que es donde debes procesar la respuesta de tu petición.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aquí todo bien. Ahora, para entender el funcionamiento del RecyclerView, debes saber que por buena practica, no debes crear un adaptador para cada resultado que obtienes, sino crear el adaptador e ir notificándole los cambios.

Tu problema es que primero se ejecuta `showLoadData(lstRequisicionData);` y una vez que llega el resultado asíncrono, entonces llenas la lista lstRequisicionData, pero nunca notificas los cambios al adaptador.

---

**Solución recomendada**

1. Debes crear el adaptador **una sola vez**, si estas en un `Activity`, créalo en el `onCreate`. Los adaptadores manejan **solo una referencia** de un objeto de tipo lista, por lo que te recomiendo crear una lista global que es la que va a manejar el adaptador.

   ```
   private List<GetDataAdapter> mlstRequisicionData = new ArrayList<>();
   ```

en el `onCreate`, le pasas la referencia de la lista global:

```
    mAdapter = new DeleteRequisicionData(getApplicationContext(), mlstRequisicionData );
```

2. Solo debes procesar los resultados, con tu lista global, no crear nuevas referencias.

   ```
   private void jsonObjectRequest() {
               try{
                   T_Configuraciones_DBManager t_configuraciones_dbManager = new T_Configuraciones_DBManager(getApplicationContext());
                   T_Configuraciones t_configuraciones = t_configuraciones_dbManager.ConsultarConfiguracion(Cons.CONFIGURACION_URL);
                   String JSON_URL =  t_configuraciones.getCon_URL() + "/GetReferenciaData";

                   final JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, JSON_URL,null,
                           new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                           {
                               @Override
                               public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                                   // Esta es la lista global
                                   mlstRequisicionData.clear();

                                   JSONArray mJsonArray = null;
                                   try {
                                       mJsonArray = response.getJSONArray("recordset");
                                       for(int i=0; i < mJsonArray.length(); i++){
                                           JSONObject mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                           GetDataAdapter requisicionData = new GetDataAdapter();
                                           requisicionData.setCodigo(mJsonObject.getString("Nro_Dcto"));
                                           requisicionData.setFecha( mJsonObject.getString("Fecha"));
                                           mlstRequisicionData.add(requisicionData);
                                       }


                                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lstRequisicionData.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                                   }
                                    // Notifica los cambios al adaptador
                                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                               }
                           },
                           new Response.ErrorListener()
                           {
                               @Override
                               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                               }
                           }
                   );

                   queue.add(getRequest);
               }catch (Error e){
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
   ```

Como recomendación extra, te sugiero que investigues las tecnicas para popular data en el `RecyclerView` de manera mas eficiente, como por ejemplo [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil).